# Xamarin.Android without the 'android:exported' property set error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-12

When Xamarin.Android is set to Android 12, I received

> "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity,
> activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but
> without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be
> installed on Android 12 or higher. See:
> developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported"

error while uploading the APK to the Google Play Console for new release.

I have added the the Exported attribute to my activities and services, yet still setting this error.

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/AppDrawerName", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", RoundIcon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, Exported = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
```

Service

```
[Service(Exported = true)]
    public class BarcodeService : IBarcodeService
    {
```

From the compile output I can see the message below

> Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.stats' used in: AndroidManifest.xml,
> AndroidManifest.xml.
>
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element
> <service#crc640921eac73192168e.PNMessagingService>. Apps targeting
> Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for
> `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent
> filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

Then I go into the "obj/Debug" folder to open the Manifest, I can see the below service is auto generated

```
<service android:name="crc640921eac73192168e.PNMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
```

Anybody know how can I set `[Service(Exported = true)]` for this service since it's auto generated?

Comment: Tried setting it to false?

Comment: No help still cannot. I have nuget added, I wonder if those nuget would add any activity or service which is not set?

Comment: Look at the resulting AndroidManifest in the `obj/Debug/Android` folder and see what is actually being exported

Comment: looking at the output manifest file in obj/Debug/Android i find the service with "intent-filter" but that not have "android:exported" set

Comment: When you find the activity or service from the Manifest inside the obj/Debug/Android, you should copy and paste it into your original Manifest and simply add the "android:exported = false" attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After got the info from the "obj/Debug" AndroidManifest.xml of the below

I added it into my project's Manifest manually under the  tag, finally it's working. Please see below for the Manifest in project.

```
<application android:label="XXXXX">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/super_red" />
    <service android:name="crc640921eac73192168e.PNMessagingService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

It's good to check the Manifest on the obj/ folder to ensure all  has exported set in the parent.

Comment: You are my HERO! Welcome to Ukraine!

Answer (score 9):

I decorated my FirebaseIIDService.cs file in my Android project with
`[Service(Exported = true)]` which did the trick. If you cannot find this file in your project, just search for `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT`

```
[Service(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseIIDService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnNewToken(string token) {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => {
            //
            // this call will only work once we have valid configuration data populated
            // upon first install, false will be returned
            await Umbraco.UpdateFirebaseToken(token);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be considered as the right solution because adding the android exported in a generated AndroidManifest.xml does not make sense if the file will be auto-generated again. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @B0r1 this is in the .cs file, not the manifest, therefore, no, it would not be re-generated.

Comment: already fixed that but thanks for mentioning! xD

Answer (score 1):

problem solution

1 - copy the generated androidManifest in the obj/debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml folder, copy and paste it in the application's main androidManifest

2- include android:exported="true" in:

activity
receiver
service

This solution solved the problem for me.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. FWIW, I only copied the specific stanzas that needed to be annotated with `android:exported="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

A friend advised me not to use API 31 as it had known issues. I first had to upgrade my Visual Studio then installed API 33. After that I cleaned and rebuilt the Xamarin [Android] project. When I tried to Archive it, the process failed and it gave an error this time around. Apparently, there is another generated AndroidManifest.xml file. This time I got the error and realised it was coming from a service I had created in the [ProjectName].Droid.Services. All I had to do was to add `Exported = true` as follows:

```
using Firebase.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp.Droid.Services
{
    [Service(Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class AppFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
         // code here
    }
}
```

I then clean, rebuilt, and archived successfully. The upload to Google Play Store was also successful.

Answer (score -1):

A Detailed output MSBuild project output verbosity did the trick.

[image]

When I turned on this feature I discovered a NotificationPushService and a TokenService element needed to add a android:exported="true" tag.

Comment: This is not the solution for the problem we are having.